# Issues displaying mysql data with EJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to render data the user posts to mysql in some ejs pages but the app is crashing.
The EJS does not appear to be sending the values.

JAVASCRIPT:
// Showing Data // Showing Data// Showing Data // Showing Data//

```
        app.get('/personal-account', (req, res) => {
            connection.query('Select ?` From `questions` order by date', 
        function (err, result) {
                //Research how to insert data
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Record Retrieved");
            });
            res.render('personal-account', {
                personal: answers
            })
        });
```

//EJS:

```
"""<div"">""<%= personal %></div>
```

The sql err says it is selecting ? but the ejs docs suggest the ? is used to send data.  Please tell me why this is not working and what I am missing.

Also my ejs html doesn't actually have all those quotes.

THANK YOU
HAPPY CODING

Comment: You normally can't use column names as placeholder values. Do you mean `SELECT *`?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64564483/edit) and post the full `ejs` code and the error message that you're receiving.

Comment: There also an extra `\`` in the query string.